# Xcode 12.5 fail resolving SwiftPackageDependency with .systemLibrary target on M1

Tags: xcode, homebrew, swift-package-manager, pkg-config

Xcode 12.5 on MBP with M1 fails resolving package dependency with .systemLibrary target. Running Xcode without Rosseta.

The project is setup with 2 spm packages. Both of them added to the project .xcworkspace and only one of them linked within the app. Both packages are local dependencies.
`A` package has `B` package as dependency and `B` package has `libgit2` as .systemLibrary dependency.
Then, if I open the project, Xcode can't find pkg-config and then not resolves libgit2 dependency.

This doesn't happens if I generate the A `pbxproj` with `swift package generate-xcodeproj`, in this case, the project resolves fine and I can build it without any problem.

The A `Package.swift` is:

```swift
// swift-tools-version:5.3
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "A",
    platforms: [
        .macOS(.v11)
    ],
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "A",
            targets: ["A"]
        ),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        .package(path: "../B")
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "A",
            dependencies: ["B"]
        ),
        .testTarget(
            name: "ATests",
            dependencies: ["A"]
        ),
    ]
)
```

The B `Package.swift` is:

```swift
// swift-tools-version:5.3
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "B",
    platforms: [
        .macOS(.v11)
    ],
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "B",
            targets: ["B"]
        )
    ],
    dependencies: [],
    targets: [
        .systemLibrary(
            name: "Clibgit2",
            pkgConfig: "libgit2",
            providers: [
                .brew(["libgit2"])
            ]
        ),
        .target(
            name: "B",
            dependencies: [
                .target(name: "Clibgit2")
            ]
        ),
        .testTarget(
            name: "BTests",
            dependencies: ["B"]
        )
    ]
)
```

The `Clibgit2` target is well configured with the `module.modulemap` and `shim.h` files.

[image: Xcode error]

I checked `pkg-config` is installed and has the libgit2 package info with `pkg-config --list`
Also I opened the project on an intel mac and is working fine.

libgit2 is installed by brew.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to NeoNach!!
Xcode is only looking at `/opt/brew` and `/usr/local`. The homebrew location for M1 chips is on `/opt/homebrew` so you can set a custom path using `com.apple.dt.Xcode.IDEHombrePrefixPath`.

`defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode IDEHomebrewPrefixPath /opt/homebrew`

Tweet ref: https://twitter.com/NeoNacho/status/1412514541343166467

Comment: still needed...?